# Why did we require standards like RMI, Corba etc?

Tags: rmi, rpc, corba

Pardon if my question sounds naive.

I am unable to wrap my head around this. I don't understand the motivation behind RMI, CORBA, etc ? I mean if the idea is to use a functionality available somewhere else and that somewhere else is accessible through network, why can't we just use a protocol like HTTP. In fact all a software application/module/package should do is to be available over the network and publish the kind of services it can provide. And then when someone requests a service just respond with the resultant data. Since HTTP and TCP are such universal protocols, using them would mean that entire Internet can access them. That's what we do in Web-Services.

So what was the motivation behind RMI, CORBA and other such standards ?

Please provide some history and perspective.

This question is in the same spirit as: [CORBA, RMI and SOA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7327524/959126)

Comment: Arent (many? all?) RPC calls via HTTP ? A SOAP Request is a RPC request,.. WSDL is RPC,...

Comment: Thanks Dan, what I mean is that why did we go for so many custom protocols like RMI, CORBA etc ?

Comment: Because people can't agree

Comment: Many things have been invented, all with their advantages and disadvantages, if you don't like one thing or it does not suit your needs, why bother about it. Requirements and possibilities change over time,..

Comment: Dan you are absolutely right. What I want to understand is the different requirements/motivations behind these custom protocols. Any particular problem they were trying to solve which couldn't be solved otherwise.

Comment: Queuing or parallel processing, different performance (lower OSI network layer), accessibility (like 'port 80 is open anyways'), security, blocking - nonblocking, synchron asyncronous, handshakes, parameter verification (per protocol definition, or individually in the application),.. many differences!

Comment: Have a look at some dates. RPC: Sun, 1983, in one incarnation, and there were others. CORBA: OMG 1989. HTTP: Berners-Lee, about 1990. RMI: Sun 1995. Commercialization of the Internet: 1990 or so. Web Services: late 1990s. And I hope you don't really think HTTP is the answer to everything.

Comment: Just about everything else you've mentioned -- including HTTP -- is built on top of TCP, so it isn't an "either/or". (And TCP is built on top of IP.) See, f'rex, http://www.e-cartouche.ch/content_reg/cartouche/formats/en/html/Internet_TCP_IP.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that Sun RMI (1995) is based on Modula-3 network objects (c. 1989).

Comment: Thanks one and all. I believe I could not express the correct intention of my question. I was trying to understand the pros/cons between RMI, CORBA, HTTP etc. The fault lies in the way I asked the question. Thanks a lot for all your help. I have edited the question to reflect my intention in a more appropriate way.

Comment: I can't see that your edit makes any substantive difference. Your question is still based on an anachronism, and the fallacy that HTTP is the answer to everything. It isn't, and it wasn't invented first.

Comment: You can try search in the web before write a question like this. Noone riquire CORBA nor HTTP. Maybie this answer can help your understand about the rise of Webservice: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13450269/205034 and http://www2002.org/CDROM/alternate/395/

Answer (score 1):

This is in some ways like asking why more than one programming language exists. Someone invents the network and the idea of transferring data across the network. Someone invents the idea of using the data to trigger actions remotely -- the client/server model. Someone invents the idea of abstracting the client/server interactions into something that looks more like function calls, and you have the general category of RPC (remote procedure call) protocols. Someone makes that object-oriented, and you have CORBA; someone wraps CORBA in Java and you have EJBs. And so on.

The older versions remain in use because there's existing code which uses them, and if you want to talk to those machines you have to talk their language... and because they're perfectly adequate, just as older programming languages are perfectly adequate. The newer ones are a bit more expressive and a bit more convenient and a bit better integrated into the concepts that newer languages use.

Welcome to computing. Blink and you'll miss a generation of development. (A bit less so now than it used to be, admittedly.)

Comment: Plus, of course, all the issues @DanFromGermany pointed out. Different tradeoffs of flexibility versus convenience versus efficiency. I wrote a multicast datagram-based protocol once, many moons ago, when that was what we needed for massive parallel update of 300 machines on a network which wouldn't otherwise have been able to handle the task that quickly... Pick the tool to suit the task.